# Hong Kong Disneyland priority tickets

Tags: hong-kong, disney

Some amusement parks - like Universal in Singapore - have priority/fast-track tickets, which allow customers to get priority treatment in queues for rides. Does Hong Kong Disneyland have that kind of tickets? I couldn't find them on their website.

Comment: https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/faq/fastpass/

Answer (score 5):

Hong Kong Disneyland has [the FASTPASS system](https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/guest-services/fastpass/), though only at three attractions. You can obtain a pass, then come back at the specified time and enter through a special queue for a "minimal wait in line." There is no additional charge for this.

There is the option of a VIP "[Disney Spectacular Tour](https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/tours/disney-spectacular-tour/)." This is quite expensive indeed: HKD$5,688 for three hours for up to six people (+ $1,600/hour after that), plus park admission. You'll get a personal guide who will show you around the park, including "direct entrance to rides of your choosing."